# Get Instagram public profile data with web search

Tags: php, instagram, web-search

I try to retrieve some public profile data from instagram without take a use of the API. I already used `file_get_contents` and extract the `_sharedData`. But this method slow down the performance extremly (5 Seconds to load) so for production it is nonesense.

I've seen in one [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906301/how-to-get-other-pages-followers-count-number-in-instagram), that they called http://instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?query=user_id to access at least the number of followers. But there are no further details.

Is there any documentation about this web search or some solution to access public profile data with instagrams web search? I need at least the counts for media, followers and followed-by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `?__a=1` to the url and get json only:

```
https://www.instagram.com/facebook/?__a=1
```

It contains public profile data which you've mentioned:

```
user:
    follows:
        count
    followed_by:
        count
    media:
        count
```

It tooks about 280ms for me.

Comment: You are awesome! :) How did you find out about `?_a=1`?

Comment: @rNix thanks, it's good ) Do you know if it possible to get next page as now it returns not all posts?

Comment: are there other websites that gives us such gold like this !?

Comment: is it working in 2020 ? i am getting login page of instagram, in localhost it is working fine